# Extracting Data from URL VBA getting IE not suppoting

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I have been using the following Excel VBA macro to bring back data from a website. It worked fine until a few days ago when the website stopped supporting IE. Of course the macro just fails now as there is no data on the webpage to bring back to Excel,  Is there a way to have the "Get method" (MSXML2.XMLHTTP)

here is my Code

```
    Public Sub GGGG()
        Dim MSX As Object
        Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
        Dim URL As String
        Dim UrlResponse As String
        Dim N As Long
        Dim sht1, sht2 As Worksheet

       ' On Error Resume Next
        Set MSX = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        Set HTML = New HTMLDocument
        

        URL = "https://www.justdial.com/Agra/Yogi-General-Store-Opp-Eclave-Satiudum-Sadar-Bazaar/0562P5612-5612-120207212812-H5I2_BZDET"
                    
                    With MSX
                        .Open "GET", URL, False
                        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
                        .send
                        UrlResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
                    End With

                       ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = UrlResponse

                    
    End Sub
```

I get response like

Error
An error occurred while processing your request.

Reference #97.ec8a2c31.1621136928.281f3ca8

Please anyone can support me how to get data when IE dose not support
I am not an expert in coding

Comment: It is the website not the browser.

Comment: is there any solution ? for that

Comment: if I use same Url in chrom its showing, but when i use macro that not work

Comment: I tried a variety of browsers and non browser methods to no avail.

Comment: thanks sir for your try.. is there any other method to grab that data instead of VBA

Comment: As I think it is the website I would say no. I tried in different languages - same result. Whether it affects all users or region based, I don't know. I suspect strongly it is the site.

Comment: Try navigating to that page via a search on the home page.

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue while scraping data from that site using selenium in combination with vba. Here is a [demo](https://imgur.com/tswgA4q) representing how it performed. Let me know If I got anything wrong.

Comment: but if you use url direct in to any browser its open esaly

Comment: @sim Please can you share with me selenium code

Comment: @Sim I look your Demo video its working as i want

Comment: The correct url for me is to use `https://www.justdial.com/Agra/Yogi-General-Store-Sadar-Bazaar/0562P5612-5612-120207212812-H5I2_BZDET`  That works fine across browsers except IE.

Comment: I have 1000s url same i don't know how to workout.. its not working.. is there some problem with cookies and bowers history. its work fine when I delete cookies and history after attempt every single url....

Comment: IF i open that url in any another browsers... its open perfectly.. but not working with IE

Comment: Thanks to all friends.. I got solution.. automatically... I just remover   _BZDET   from URL and it working now best as before work... i dont know but its work... before it was work perfefet with _BZDET but now it work without it

Comment: can anybody suggest me what is it.. and why its working well will this new minor changes...I just wondering to know something strange

Comment: website was updated? Happens

Comment: @QHarr did you try at your end with removing _BZDET  . is it working there with IE ?. may it IE update as i think.. regaridng "_" they change something in IE.. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, try this to get the title and votes from that site using vba in combination with selenium.

```
Sub FetchInfo()
    Dim driver As Object, oTitle As Object
    Dim oVotes As Object
    
    Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
    
    driver.get "https://www.justdial.com/Agra/Yogi-General-Store-Opp-Eclave-Satiudum-Sadar-Bazaar/0562P5612-5612-120207212812-H5I2_BZDET"
    Set oTitle = driver.FindElementByCss("span.item > span", Raise:=False, timeout:=10000)
    Set oVotes = driver.FindElementByCss("span.rtngsval > span.votes", Raise:=False, timeout:=10000)
    Debug.Print oTitle.Text, oVotes.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When the webpage no longer support IE in future, you can try out web **scrape** using Google Chrome with new add-in installed, please see following link for the add-in installation adn how to write in VBA. However, it is in my opinion the most simple way to perform your work is to use Uipath free community version, it work for all type of web-browser.

VBA guideline:
https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/vba-macros/videos/vba-scrape-websites/web-scraping-selenium-chrome/

VBA library installation for Selenium:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/selenium-vba/downloads

Comment: I try with selenium Chrome ... same issue still going on

Comment: Quite bad to hear it, if VBA is giving you alot trouble, there is other tools that can always help you. Come with Web automation, VBA not always my preferred tool. Good luck and hope you can solve the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the *Feature Browser Emulation* to *zero* as detailed by Daniel here:

[Everything You Never Wanted to Know About the Access WebBrowser Control](https://www.devhut.net/2019/10/18/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-the-access-webbrowser-control/#Emulation)

That said, your URL fails even when opened in Edge Chromium, so the site may suffer from a general failure.